# how to chain 2 commands on terminal

Tags: python, terminal, julia

I am trying to use subprocess in my python script to open Julia and then run a script.

To run on my machine, I enter this in terminal:

```
$ julia
$ include(test.jl); func("in.csv", "out.csv")
```

How do I replicate this process and chain both of these commands so that I can run from subprocess in a single call?

I've tried `julia; include(test.jl); func("in.csv", "out.csv")` and `julia && include(test.jl) && func("in.csv", "out.csv")`

but both result in

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"test.jl"`
```

Comment: `julia; anything` doesn't do `anything` until after `julia` exited. Feed your things that are supposed to be run by julia _as stdin to_ julia.

Comment: that's the same for anything else. `ssh somehost; do-something-else` doesn't run `do-something-else` until `ssh` exited.

Comment: If you read https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/getting-started/, it tells you how to embed julia code on a command line. It's effectively equivalent to the R-specific method in the question I'm linking as a duplicate.

Comment: Also, look at heredocs. `julia <<EOF`, then your Julia code, then `EOF` will feed that code as stdin to julia.

Comment: I don't think that duplicate addresses the question here — which isn't about Bash but rather about Python's `subprocess.run`.  Someone who already knows the answer can probably make the leap between the two, but it's likely wholly unhelpful for someone who doesn't.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there _is_ a more relevant duplicate, but I couldn't find one immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that you're not really chaining two commands from the standpoint of Python's `subprocess`. There's just *one* command: `julia`.  You want to pass a somewhat complicated *argument* to Julia that will execute multiple *Julia* expressions.

In short, you just want to do:

```py
subprocess.run(['julia','-e','include("test.jl"); func("in.csv", "out.csv")'])
```

What's happening here is that you're just executing *one* subprocess, `julia`, started up with the `-e` command line flag that just runs whatever comes next in Julia.  You can optionally use the capitalized `-E` flag instead which will print out whatever `func` (your last expression there) returns.

It's worth pointing out, though, that there [are better ways](https://pyjulia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of getting Julia and Python interoperating — especially if you need to transfer data back and forth.